# Великий Бард (=Шекспир)

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Как правильно записать перифраз для имени великого английского драматурга: ***В***еликий **Б**ард или ***в***еликий **б**ард?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если перифраз употребляется в качестве приложения, то оба слова со строчной буквы: великий бард Шекспир.

Если самостоятельно, то, вероятно, по аналогии с перифразом имени Тэтчер (Розенталь даёт варианты - "железная леди" и Железная леди, так же как псевдонимы и прозвища): "великий бард" и Великий бард.

Но иногда встречается употребление перифраза в поэтическом тексте, где подчёркивается уважение к нему, тогда возможно и оба слова написать с большой буквы: Великий Бард, это как родина и Родина, Государственная дума (по правилам) и Государственная Дума (подчёркивание значительности).

Так что смотря где и с какой целью пишется.